# Comparing two lists and deleting identical results c#

Tags: c#, list, comparison

I have two lists:

```
List<int> positionsThatCannotBeMovedTo =...
List<int> desiredLocations =...
```

I am trying to remove all of the positions which cannot be moved to from the desired locations to create a list of safe positions:

```
List<int> safePositions = new List<int>(uniquePositions);
safePositions.RemoveAll(positionsThatCannotBeMovedTo);
```

however it's throwing the error:

"Argument1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Predicate'

I'm not entirely sure what this means or how I'm misusing the function. Is anybody able to explain this for me please? I am doing it this way because of the answer in this question:

[Compare two lists for updates, deletions and additions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667481/compare-two-lists-for-updates-deletions-and-additions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RemoveAll` takes a `Predicate<T>`, but you are passing a list:

```
safePositions.RemoveAll(x => positionsThatCannotBeMovedTo.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to obtain a list with elements except the elements of another list

```
List<int> positionsThatCannotBeMovedTo = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
List<int> uniquePositions = new List<int>() {5,6,7,8,9,10};
List<int> safePosition = uniquePositions.Except(positionsThatCannotBeMovedTo).ToList();
```

MSDN on [`Enumerable<T>.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this using the Except extension method. Assuming uniquePositions is your list of all your positions.

```
var safePositions = uniquePositions.Except(positionsThatCannotBeMovedTo).ToList();
```

Except is the set difference operator and as you are using lists of ints the default comparer is fine.